# Inconsistency in java date library for week of year

Tags: java, hive, simpledateformat, datetime-format, week-number

As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates, Weekdays start on Monday. But, from Java, if you try to extract week number in two different ways, two different outputs come if the date is a Sunday.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final SimpleDateFormat weekFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ww");
        String date = "2018-10-21";
        System.out.println(weekFormatter.format(formatter.parse(date)));
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        calendar.setTime(formatter.parse(date));
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
43
42
```

Is this an inconsistency?

This is just a test program I wrote to reproduce the issue, I noticed the problem in Hive, like the following:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://zk0-something> select from_unixtime(t, 'ww'), weekofyear(from_unixtime(t, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) from (select 1540122033 as t) a;
+------+------+--+
| _c0  | _c1  |
+------+------+--+
| 43   | 42   |
+------+------+--+
1 row selected (0.388 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://zk0-something>
```

Comment: Don't blame `SimpleDateFormat`, blame your default locale which defines Sunday as the first day of week. If you want "correct" values (well, depends on the point of view), then use the locale of a country which defines Monday as the first day of week, like France (`new SimpleDateFormat("ww", Locale.FRANCE)`)

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time

```
    String date = "2018-10-21";
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date);
    int weekOfYear = ld.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear());
    System.out.println(weekOfYear);
```

Output:

> 42

Since you are interested in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) rules [for week numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), use [`WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) for getting week related data from a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). You may also use a [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) if you like:

```
    DateTimeFormatter weekFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ww", Locale.FRANCE);
    System.out.println(ld.format(weekFormatter));
```

Output is the same:

> 42

The locale passed to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` determines the week scheme. If I pass [`Locale.US`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) instead, I get 43.

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and stay away from the old date-time classes like `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. The old ones were poorly designed and the modern ones are much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

Both the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class and the modern `DateTimeFormatter` take their week numbering scheme from their locale. If no locale is specified for the formatter, it uses the default locale of the JVM. So if the JVM has American locale, for example, the formatter will print 43 in your first example because in the US Sunday October 21 this year was in week 43. If the locale is French, it will print 42 because that day was in week 42 in France. France follows the ISO 8601 standard, the USA does not.

In your example, setting the `Calendar`’s first day of week to Monday causes the week number to be 42 as you had expected. This will not always be the case, however. Week numbers are defined not only by the first day of the week but also by the definition of week 1. From your link:

> The first ISO week of a year may have up to three days that are
>   actually in the Gregorian calendar year that is ending; if they are
>   Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday. Similarly, the last ISO week of a year
>   may have up to three days that are actually in the Gregorian calendar
>   year that is starting; if they are Friday, Saturday, and Sunday. The
>   Thursday of each ISO week is always in the Gregorian calendar year
>   denoted by the ISO week-numbering year.

The American definition of which week is week 1 is different: In the US January 1 is always in week 1. Therefore if your `Calendar` is created with American locale, setting its first day of week to Monday is not enough to make is follow ISO 8601 rules. Coincidentally, for 2018 the week numbers agree, though.